# Remove Send Message Button From contact list view

Tags: lightning, salesforce-id

Can you Please help me in removing SendMessage button[image] from contact recently viewed List view(Standard List view)

Comment: Can you try unchecking the permission 'Send One-to-Many Messages' under the permission set?

Comment: It worked ,after removing the permission from permission set the button is removed from layout

Comment: Great,  and I have posted same as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Contact in the object manager, then to Search Layouts for Classic.
Click on edit for the List View layout, and there you can select which buttons you want to show on that list view.

[image]

Comment: I have done that even after that the button is still showing on list view

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the permission 'Send One-to-Many Messages' under the permission set and that should hide/remove 'Send Message' button from the layout.